# How to encode a python dictionary and decode in jquery? (via a cookie)

Tags: python, parsing, cookies, urllib

I am trying to save a python dictionary in a cookie and then be able to convert the cookie value back to a dict in jquery or javascript.  I'm using python 3.3.1.   I'm getting confused on formats ( query strings, json, etc).

I'm using this jquery cookie library

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

I have tried the following:

server side:

```
import urlib.parse
d= {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}
cookie_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(d)
```

client side:

```
cookie_data = $.cookie('Cookie_Name');
var dict = $.parseJson(cookie_data);
```

What is the correct way of doing it so I end up with a valid dictionary on the client side?

I also have tried using:

server side:

```
d = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}
cookie_data = json.dumps(d)
```

Which gets me the desired json data in a string.

cookie_data now is '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'

However when I send it as a cookie the string comes out like this

"\173\"key2\": \"value2\"\054 \"key1\": \"value1\"\175"

That's why I thought I needed to encode it somehow.

I have also tried:

```
var cookie_str = $.cookie('My_cookie');
var decoded_cookie = decodeURIComponent(cookie_str);
```

both cookie_str and decoded_cookie are the same

\173"key2": "value2"\054 "key1": "value1"\175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by doing this server side:

```
import urlib.parse, json
cookie_data = urllib.parse.quote(json.dumps(mydict))
```

client side using jquery

```
var dict = $.parseJSON($.cookie('MyCookie'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using console logging in JS can be very useful to debug what info is being sent back and forth.

```
console.log(cookie_data)
```

will print what is actually stored in `$.cookie('Cookie_Name');`

The problem here is that you're storing url-encoded values in the server: `key1=value1&key2=value2`, but you want the json: `{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}`. You need to encode the data into JSON format on the server, as that's what the client is expecting.

`repr` will get you close, but it uses single-quotes and the JSON standard specifies double-quotes for strings. Your client may accept this, but to conform to the standard, as well as escaping other data, you should use a python library for encoding JSON, such as `simplejson`:

```
>>> simplejson.JSONEncoder().encode({'k':'v', 'k2': 'v2'})
'{"k2": "v2", "k": "v"}'
>>> repr({'k':'v', 'k2': 'v2'})
"{'k2': 'v2', 'k': 'v'}"
```

Comment: I added more info to my post.  I originally converted the dict to a string containing the proper json.  It's when I send it via a cookie and get the escape chars and such.  I'm having trouble decoding it.  So I'm really not sure if i'm sending the correct way or just not using the proper tools on the client side to decode it.  Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: The HTTP protocol is escaping the special characters in the response. You need to use decodeURIComponent()

Comment: I tried decodeURIComponent() and it does not affect the string at all.

Comment: How did you call it? It should not change the string, but it should return the decoded string.

Comment: It looks like if the backslashes are escaped in the string, there's not really a lot you can do with decodeURIComponent. Have you tried to set $.cookie.json = 1 and hoping it parses for you, or $.cookie.raw = 1 and decoding it yourself?